# Laravel - update is incrementing the ID?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Hello guys,

I'm making an API using Laravel. In one of my scripts, I make an update on a field, like this :

```
user::where('uuid', $uuid)->update(['date' => $date]);
```

I noticed that the primary key increments when doing this. My obvious conclusion is that Eloquent makes a delete - insert in place of a regular MySQL update.

And so the question is, why ?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Is will be good if you used Model to update the database table.

Comment: And that's.... Not what I'm currently doing ? Sorry, Laravel beginner :)

Comment: Can we see your migration file?

Comment: Would recommend you to change your field name date to created_at or others as there are date inbuilt function in mysql

Comment: @SonuSindhu He clearly is using the model, and it doesn't matter that `date` is an inbuilt function since he's using eloquent.

Comment: It's not possible primary key increments with this update (unless you have some DB triggers defined). You should analyse your code in details what exactly is being launched

Comment: It is also possible that you have some model events that when updating create new record and remove old one

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek you are right ! Didn't even think of this... If you want to put your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks !

Comment: @JeremyBelolo I've added answer, could you please tell me which guess was right - DB trigger or Laravel event?

Comment: The model events :) thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible that this line of code will update id your records. Whenever you thing something strange happens in your application (not only in Laravel), you should:

- analyse what exactly code is running that causes this problem (for example you think the error is in this line but you execute also some other custom function where error might occur)
- verify if there are no extra framework dependant code launched - in this case events for `user` model
- verify if there are no triggers in Database (that will automatically update/insert/delete records)